# RegionUnion looses MeshRegion's Markers

Tags: mesh

The following code shows the prescripted MeshCellMarkers **1** and **2** as expected :

```
$Version  

myDiscretize[region_] := 
 DiscretizeRegion[region, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Marker"}
  , MeshCellMarker -> {{0, 1} -> 1, {0, 2} -> 2}]  

RegionUnion[
 myDiscretize[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}(*,{1,.5}*)}]]
 , myDiscretize[Line[{{0, .3}, {.3, .3}}]]
 ]
```

[image]

but if I uncomment the code `(* ,{1,.5} *)`, then the markers diseappear :

```
$Version  

myDiscretize[region_] := 
 DiscretizeRegion[region, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Marker"}
  , MeshCellMarker -> {{0, 1} -> 1, {0, 2} -> 2}]  

RegionUnion[
 myDiscretize[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, .5}}]]
 , myDiscretize[Line[{{0, .3}, {.3, .3}}]]
 ]
```

[image]

It's not a problem of visual rendering : The `Inputform` of the above expression shows that the marker informations are really lost.

I find this problem unpredictable. Is there a *robust* workaround, or at least a way to predict when it will work ?

This problem is still present in Mathematica Version 13.1  (tried in the Wolfram Cloud)

**Edit**

Curiously, if I move the small segment below, it's working again :

```
$Version

myDiscretize[region_] := 
 DiscretizeRegion[region, MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Marker"}, 
  MeshCellMarker -> {{0, 1} -> 1, {0, 2} -> 2}]

RegionUnion[myDiscretize[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, .5}}]], 
 myDiscretize[Line[{{0, -.3}, {.3, -.3}}]]]
```

> 12.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 12, 2020)

[image]

Comment: `RegionUnion` will `Union` the points, the index will rearrange.  `reg1 = Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, .5}}];
reg2 = Line[{{0, .3}, {.3, .3}}];
{HighlightMesh[reg1, Labeled[0, "Index"]],
 HighlightMesh[reg2, Labeled[0, "Index"]],
 HighlightMesh[RegionUnion[reg1, reg2], Labeled[0, "Index"]]}`

Comment: `{myDiscretize[Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, .5}}]],
  myDiscretize[Line[{{0, .3}, {.3, .3}}]]} // Show`